# outerHeight() method returning a string data type instead of a number data type

Tags: jquery

I need the jquery method of `outerHeight()` to return a number data type instead of a string data type.

```
var firstTd = $.trim($(this).find("td:first").outerHeight());
alert(typeof firstTd); // output ---> string 
alert(firstTd); // output ---> 58
```

and I triedusing parseInt

```
var firstTd = $.trim(parseInt($(this).find("td:first").outerHeight()),10);
alert(typeof firstTd); // output ---> string 
alert(firstTd); // output ---> 58
```

How can I get this output to say number as the data type?

Comment: its not a number. you are using jQuery trim, which always returns a string

Comment: @chiliNUT - good eyes, didn't even notice, why would anyone trim a number ?

Comment: @adeneo thanks, my guess would be they are new to jQuery, or maybe what was originally being trimmed made sense, but he replaced it with something else

Comment: I thought trim means to remove empty spaces not convert into a string.

Comment: A real number does not have “empty spaces” in the first place – _because_ it is a number.

Comment: ^ ding, only strings have spaces, other datatypes don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by simply removing the `$.trim()` from around the rest of the code. You're already receiving an integer, so there's nothing more to trim from it. So, use this:

```
var firstTd = $(this).find("td:first").outerHeight();
alert(typeof firstTd); // output ---> number
alert(firstTd); // output ---> 58
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

parseInt(). It does not require jquery

Comment: There is no need to use parseInt because outerHeight is already a number. That is, unless the OP specifically wants to an integer value.

Comment: I made the assumption that $.trim() was being used for a purpose beyond what was disclosed here in the code sample. Assumptions! I know and guilty as charged.

Answer (score 0):

You are including outerHeight within the trim function, which converts it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!

```
var firstTd = Number($.trim($(this).find("td:first").outerHeight()));
alert(typeof firstTd); // output ---> number now 
alert(firstTd); // output ---> 58
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a request for clarification. Please post this as a comment instead.

Comment: is this a solution now :)

Comment: Nope, that code doesn't fix it. It still keeps the variable `firstTd` as a string.

Comment: Wrapping strings in alerts will magically make them numbers, how useful ?

Comment: If you take a look at my answer above ([easy link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23705377/1256925)) you can see that what you're doing now was already my answer, except your code is a bit less efficient. I've removed my downvote though.

Comment: Does it make sense now? Yours is of course the right one. I am just trying core JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.trim will always return a string. If you want to use parseInt, then use it on the return value of $.trim().